# Change font in Console.app

Tags: catalina, thunderbolt-display, console

Is it possible to increase the font size in Console? I am looking at a 27" Thunderbolt display sitting about 4 feet away and the tiny font is unreadable. It appears to be Menlo 11 and I need at least size 18 to read it on this display.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't change the font for Console.app OOTB with macOS

Console.app uses the font that is located in the application itself (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts/`). If you delete it, which is not recommended, the default font it will revert to Helvetiva.

Comment: I don't know what OS you are using but there is no such location in Catalina. The real Console.app is at   /System/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/ for some reason I am unable to edit to code or add a return character to this text. In addition, there is no such Fonts folder or file, however I did find a Fonts location in the Info.plist file called "Application fonts resource path" which points to somewhere called Fonts however I can't find any such location. It seems that Apple has prevented usability to the best of their ability.